# Get reference to captured video

Tags: ios, objective-c, video

I'm building an app where I want the user to capture a fixed length video and for it to be uploaded immediately after it is captured (no video selection etc., just immediate upload).

I have the following code that captures a 3 second video:

```
// Start recording

int64_t delayInSeconds = 1.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [cameraUI startVideoCapture];
    [cameraUI performSelector:@selector(stopVideoCapture) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
});
```

After that has completed, how can I get the link to the video file? I've seen a number of implementations that add another method that takes an NSDictionary as an argument, but I can't see where the NSDictionary comes from, and I would prefer to do this in the same method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`.This Delegate has a method

> - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info

`info` is the  docitionary which has URL of the video captured.